# Exercise about adjoint of densily defined operator between Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $A:D(A)\subset X \to Y$ a densily defined linear operator. Suppose the graph of $A$ is closed. Then the follwing are equivalent:

- $D(A)=X$;
- $A$ is bounded;
- $D(A^*)=Y^*$;
- $A^*$ is bounded.

I figured out the equivalence of the first three sentences. And I showed that the third implies the fourth. But I couldn't show that the fourth implies any of the others. I'm suspecting that this last implication is false. But I have no idea about how to build a counterexample (if there is one). So, is it true?

Answer (score 0):

If $A^*$ is defined as $A\left(f\right)\left(x\right)=f\left(A\left(x\right)\right)$ for all $x\in X$ and all $f\in Y'$, then we have
$$\|A^*\|_{\mathcal{L}\left(Y';X'\right)}
=\sup_{\|f\|_{Y'}=1}\|A^*\left(f\right)\|_{X'}
=\sup_{\|f\|_{Y'}=1}\sup_{\|x\|_{X}=1}|f\left(A\left(x\right)\right)|$$
$$=\sup_{\|x\|_{X}=1}\sup_{\|f\|_{Y'}=1}|f\left(A\left(x\right)\right)|
=\sup_{\|x\|_{X}=1}\|A\left(x\right)\|_Y
=\|A\|_{\mathcal{L}\left(X;Y\right)}$$

then $A$ is bounded iff $A^*$ is bounded.
Note: the above operator norms exist iff $A$ and $A^*$ are bounded, so writing them without knowing the last conditions is an abuse, but it was easier to write it like that.

Comment: Looks like you're using that $D(A)=X$ and $D(A^*)=Y^*$, which we want to prove... Are those assumptions necessary in your argument?

Comment: You've proved it, didn't you ? Anyway, taking the supremum on a set or on a dense subset is the same, so you can replace $X$ by $D\left(A\right)$ if you want.

Comment: I want to prove that the fourth implies any of the other three. And, as far as I know, $D(A^*)$ is not dense in $Y^*$.

Comment: What I meant is that you can use what I wrote once you've proved the first three equivalences. But you wrote you've done it, right ? If not, then indeed you can not use my proof...